# Asking less information from external providers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

The external logins feature that comes with the latest MVC template in VS 2013 is very useful and easy to use.  However, is there any way to change the level of information that is being asked from the external provider?

I need just the provider key, not even the human readable from of the account identifier, but at present they are asking too much as follows:

1. Microsoft: profile info and **contact list**
2. Google: view your email address, view your basic **profile info**
3. Facebook: your public profile
4. Twitter: **read tweets** from your timeline, **see who you follow**

Some of the above may frighten my users from authorizing the connection.  Can the information asked be reduced?

Comment: Aren't they just the default messages for all of those providers for minimum authorisation?